# Get the number of Rows in WrapPanel?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a List Box that implements its ItemsPanelTemplate as a WrapPanel. I need to count the number of rows for navigation purposes

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
<ListBox>
```

Is there any direct way ?.

Comment: Why do you need to count the number of rows? What specific navigation task are you trying to support?

Comment: I want to use the arrow keys to navigate the list box. Currently when I press up or down the selection moves sideways rather than vertically. @DanM

Comment: Do the items in your wrap panel form a grid pattern or are the items not uniformly sized?

Comment: They do form a uniform pattern.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the `WrapPanel` is a flow control you'll have to perform the calculations to determine how many objects fit yourself.

Take the `ActualHeight` property of the `WrapPanel`, divide that by the `ActualHeight` of the item (or `ItemHeight` property of the `WrapPanel`) of the object you are placing in the panel. That should give you the number of rows:

```
int numRows = (int)(WrapPanel.ActualHeight / Item.ActualHeight);
```

or:

```
int numRows = (int)(WrapPanel.ActualHeight / WrapPanel.ItemHeight);
```

This calculation will be off if you have any margins set, but you should be able to take them into account.

(You can do the same with the `ActualWidth` and `ItemWidth` to get the number of columns).

Comment: How do I get the ActualHeight for the item?.

Comment: @Ammark - it should have that property already - you haven't said what it is though.

Comment: The Items consist of an image and a few textBlocks.

Comment: @Ammark - they must all be contained in something - `ActualHeight` is a property of a [`FrameworkElement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.height.aspx)

Comment: Chris, careful...according to the documentation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.wrappanel.aspx), `ItemHeight` is actually the height of all items combined. (At least, that's my interpretation.)

Comment: The Items consist of an image and a few textBlocks. The ItemHeight does not give me a valid value its just Nan. I could extend it and then find out the item heights. I will be back after some experimenting.